# WalletConnect not showing metamask

Tags: node.js, metamask, wallet-connect

Here's my code:

```
const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
            rpc: {
                private-testnet-chainId: "private testnet",
            },
            qrcodeModalOptions: {
                mobileLinks: [
                    "rainbow",
                    "metamask",
                ],
            },
        });

        //  Enable session (triggers QR Code modal)
        await provider.enable();
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

However, I do not see the metamask option:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mobileLinks` array is specifically for mobile devices, and does not impact desktop usage or display. The QR code can be used to access Metamask on desktop.